# How to have a script wait for PowerShell on a remote server without using Restart-Computer

Tags: powershell, error-handling, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

Afternoon guys,

I'm working on a script that creates an initial Domain Controller. I've been running into an error and I feel like it's related to the creation of the Forest and the server restarting. The error in question is

```
powershell remoting processing data from remote server failed with the following error message: the I/O operation as been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request
```

I have the Forest being created through `invoke-command` and the server restarting within that script block and a timer that waits 8 mins and then restarts the server again. The issue I run into is I'm trying to pull the initial restart out of the `invoke-command` scriptblock but it's giving me Access Denied permission errors.

```
The computer is skipped. Fail to retrieve its LastBootUpTime via the WMI service with
the following error message: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
```

Now if I have the restart within the `invoke-command` block so it runs locally on the server, the only error I get is the first one. If I pull it out I get the second error, which I know the credentials are correct as it's the same credentials I use when running `invoke-command` (The account in question is the built-in administrator for the initial build-out).

Below is a block of my code, I guess my real question is, what would be causing my first error with the `remote operation failing`

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $IP -Credential $AdminCred -ScriptBlock {
    Write-Output "Promoting to Primary Domain Controller... "
    Install-ADDSForest -DomainName $using:Domain -InstallDNS -NoRebootOnCompletion -Force -SkipPreChecks -SafeModeAdministratorPassword $Using:DomainAdminPass -WarningAction SilentlyContinue

    Restart-Computer -Force
}

#What I've also tried but gives the Access Denied error
#Restart-Computer -ComputerName $IP -Credential $AdminCred -Wait -For PowerShell -Force

# Creates a Progress Bar Timer, set for 6 minutes, to wait for the server to reboot.
Write-Log "Restarting $HostName... " -NoNewLine

For($i=0; $i -le 360; $i++){
    Write-Progress -Activity "Performing Initial Configuration. This will take approx. 8 minutes" -Status "Working..." -SecondsRemaining (480 - $i)
    Sleep -s 1
}
Write-Progress -Activity "Performing Initial Configuration. This will take approx. 8 minutes" -Completed


#Performs another remote reboot of the DC to confirm it has rebooted
#DOES NOT GIVE an Access denied error, if the DC was restarted locally through invoke-command
Restart-Computer -ComputerName $IP -Credential $AdminCred -Wait -For PowerShell

#Pauses the script for 45 seconds to allow the DC to fully initialize
For($i=0; $i -le 60; $i++){
    Write-Progress -Activity "Finalizing Initial Configuration" -Status "Finalizing..." -SecondsRemaining (60 - $i)
    Sleep -s 1
}
Write-Progress -Activity "Finalizing Initial Configuration" -Completed
```

Comment: Have you tried looking into PowerShell Desired State Configuration instead? Then you can actually define what the DC should look like using a param file and just wait for DSC to get into the Success state...